# How to get meta tag content value in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'am not able to get the content value of meta tag from site in Ruby using Watir-webdriver gem.

e.g.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="【楽天市場】ダヴ メンプラスケア クリーンコンフォート泡洗顔 つめかえ用(110mL)【unili3e102】【ダヴ(Dove)】[ダヴ 洗顔]：爽快ドラッグ">
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: I am trying to do like this -

@browser.meta(:property, 'og:title').content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `browser.meta(:property, 'og:title').content` is that "property" is not a valid attribute for meta tags. As a result, Watir does not allow it as a locator method.

To locate elements via unsupported attributes, you will need to use a CSS-selector:

```
browser.meta(css: 'meta[property="og:title"]').content
```

Or use XPath:

```
browser.meta(xpath: '//meta[@property="og:title"]').content
```